# Warning: Rate limit exceeded - 88 (Rate limit exceeded) with `rtweet`

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

For some time now, thanks to package `rtweet`, I have been downloading data from Twitter. This code shows just an example (I usually use different keywords).

```
## load rtweet package
library(rtweet)

tweets1 <- search_tweets("hello beautiful world", n = 10000000, language="en", 
                                      retryonratelimit=TRUE)
tweets2 <- search_tweets("hello world", n = 10000000, language="en", 
                                      retryonratelimit=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately this time I got the following error message:

```
>tweets1 <- search_tweets("hello beautiful world", n = 10000000, language="en", 
                                      retryonratelimit=TRUE)
Downloading [=========================================] 100%
Warning: Rate limit exceeded - 88
Warning message:
Rate limit exceeded 
>tweets1 <- search_tweets("hello world", n = 10000000, language="en", 
                                      retryonratelimit=TRUE)
Warning: Rate limit exceeded - 88
Warning message:
Rate limit exceeded
```

Anyone know what this message means? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're hitting the rate limit - "...the rate limit for the standard search API is 18,000 tweets per fifteen minutes. With a bearer token, the rate limit is 45,000 tweets per fifteen minutes."  rtweet divides the calls up to avoid exceeding the limit, but perhaps you'd tried several calls in quick succession.  Not sure what "88" is though.

Comment: Facing same issue - looks like something changed at Twitter? Had no issues for years using rTweet and it would only hit the rate limit 88 after a week or 2 of downloads. Now its stopping every 18000 tweets - they may be implementing the 500,000 tweets per month limit? (just saw this number on their webpage for Developer accounts). Does anyone know of any legit workarounds /solutions for this? Will another package or Py library work?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I tried again yesterday and managed to download the tweets. Maybe it was a momentary problem with the API. @aiatay7n: and you made a new attempt?

Comment: @Mark - you are correct, just tried again with `rtweet` and it is now running past the first two batches of ~ 18000 tweets and still going on, lets see how long it lasts! :-)